# Button hyperlink dont work when several button are in activity

Tags: android, button, hyperlink

I want to have several button in activity and when touch them go to Url,  but Just one Button set link and others have unusual reaction and don't set text and Url.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="@string/antivirus" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/antivirusbtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#021f4e"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

      <Button
            android:id="@+id/antivirusbt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#021f4e"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
```

on java:
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    setContentView(R.layout.antivirus);
    Button link =(Button)findViewById(R.id.antivirusbtn);
    link.setClickable(true);
    link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    String text = "<a href = 'http://kmspico10.com/'>ESET</a>";
    link.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));


    Button link1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.antivirusbtn2);
    link1.setClickable(true);
    link1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    String text1 = "<a href = 'http://test.com/'>Macafee</a>";
    link.setText(Html.fromHtml(text1));
```

Comment: Why use a button and not a TextView for this?

Comment: I check it but have same problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set MovementMethod and clickability etc only when you want a ***TextView to appear as a link***. (something similar to link in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1QND.png)

Buttons are by default clickable and you can just launch URL in browser using intent with Action_view.

```
   Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.abcd.com/faqs.html");
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
   startActivity(intent);
```